# Rooted android device throw EACCES: permission denied exception when I try to get CPU's temperature

Tags: android, linux, permissions

I was try to get the android devices' CPU temperature, and after a little search I found some files store the data of temperature, the only thing I need is to read those files. Most specifically, I found most device contain temperature in the path "/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/temp".

I have added permission in my manifest file.

however, I found in some devices the app is running fine (4.1, 4.4, 5.1 version), in 2 extra devices, it does not work, I printed the log, it shows EACCES: permission denied

I found both those two devices have been rooted before. I used adb shell with su command and those file really exist and contain the temperature data.

Answer (score 2):

It probably failed on selinux enforced device (i.e. [device running android 5.0 and later](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/)).

You will need a custom rom, with special policies to access those file from your app, or call

> adb shell setenforce 0

to disable until next boot (on rooted phone only)